# How to access emails managed by Mozilla Thunderbird in console mode?

Tags: email, thunderbird

For some reason, I have to remote ssh to my working station and access some emails. I am curious to know if there is anyway to access emails managed by Thunderbird(3.0) in console?

Comment: Why not connect directly to the relevant IMAP server? Trying to remotely manage your client seems counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for a negative answer, but I don't believe that what you are asking is possible.

The entire list of command-line switches for Thunderbird is contained in the MozillaZine article of [Command line arguments - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29). This include a limited way for composing mail, but no switch for consulting mail without invoking the GUI interface.

Any mail-checking solution would involve configuring another terminal-oriented mail client to interface with the mail server (without using Thunderbird). But if you retrieve any mail through such a client, this mail may be missing when you later consult your account with Thunderbird.

If you wish to read mail from an existing mailbox, this [thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=91948) offers some solutions that may apply on Linux :

- `mutt -f mailbox`
- configure an imap server, make symlinks on ~/mail to point
  to the files used by thunderbird, then use an imap compatible client to read those e-mails.